# How to integrate a webhook with google assistant without using ifttt?

Tags: webhooks, google-assistant-sdk, arduino-esp8266, google-developers-console, ifttt

Im doing a project where i use a node mcu board to control lights in my house and im using a service called Blynk which provides an app like environment to interact , turn the lights on and off with virtual buttons and for each button we have a webhook that can be used.

So i want to integrate that webhook with custom google assistant commands but as i scoured the internet i only found ifttt which i already know but,  is there any way to trigger webhooks with voice command without using ifttt and using the console google thingy?
If yes can someone please explain me how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason as to why you wish to avoid IFTTT?

Comment: Using Google Actions Console requires billing to be enabled, and hence the trial activated, on Google Cloud Platform for Cloud Functions.

Comment: You can use IFTTT without going through the Google Actions Console, as it's connected to your user account and not developer account. In your specific case, this [Blynk and Google Assistant guide](https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2020/01/06/iot-4-google-assistant-with-ifttt-blynk-voice-automation/) may be a good place to stat.

Comment: The problem IFTTT is not working for me and I tried using actions console but I don't know hot to put an action where it gets a webhook